# How can I run an algorithm that produces a message in one client and send that message to another client through server in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I'm doing a project in which I have a webcam that's recording and an algorithm that detects an object in the webcam feed, tracks it and when the object reaches an area of interest in the frame, a message is produces and should be sent to an app.
I have the algorithm working and returning a message. I also managed to setup a python socket server which acts as a connection point between two clients. I want to have one client running the webcam feed and therefore the algorithm and the other client displaying the message coming from the first client.

I got the two clients to communicate but only when I send the messages manually. I also implemented the webcam feed and tracking algorithm on one client but when I start everything up, both the client that runs the algorithm and the client that displays the message connect to the server and the frame showing the webcam feed starts running but then stops responding and is just a gray screen. Everything is written in Python and the algorithm is implemented with openCV.

clientAlg.py is the client that should run the webcam feed and tracking algorithm producing and sending the message, clientMsg.py is the client receiving and displaying the message, and serverCon.py is the server connecting the two clients.

**clientAlg.py**

```
SERVER_HOST = 'localhost'
SERVER_PORT = 8080

# Create a socket object
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect to the server
client_socket.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))

def send():
    #Function to send messages to the server
    while True:
        try:
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            while True:
                _, frame = cap.read()

                hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

                roi = frame[100:700,0:200]

                cv2.imshow("roi",roi)

                #Yellow color
                low_yellow = np.array([16, 0, 0])
                high_yellow = np.array([37, 255, 255])
                yellow_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_yellow, high_yellow)
                yellow = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=yellow_mask)

                #face color
                low_face = np.array([0, 117, 208])
                high_face = np.array([179, 255, 255])
                face_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_face, high_face)
                face = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=face_mask)
                
                #face_gray = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(yellow, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                #blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)

                #cv2.imshow("Blur", blur)

                #contours, _ = cv2.findContours(face_gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
                contours, _ = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
                for cnt in contours:
                    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
                    if area > 2500:
                        #cv2.drawContours(frame, [cnt], 0, (0,255,0), 2)

                        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
                        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
                        if x < 150:
                            data = "Animal going towards the road!!!"
                            client_socket.send(data.encode())

                cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
                #cv2.imshow("yellow", yellow)
                #cv2.imshow("gray", gray)

        except:
            # If there is an error, break the loop and close the connection
            break

# Start two threads for receiving and sending messages
#send_thread = threading.Thread(target=send)

#send_thread.start()
send()
```

**clientMsg.py**

```
SERVER_HOST = 'localhost'
SERVER_PORT = 8080

# Create a socket object
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect to the server
client_socket.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))

def receive():
    """Function to receive messages from the server"""
    while True:
        try:
            # Receive data from the server
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)

            if not data:
                # If no data is received, break the loop and close the connection
                break

            # Print the received data
            print(data.decode())

        except:
            # If there is an error, break the loop and close the connection
            break

def send():
    """Function to send messages to the server"""
    while True:
        try:
            # Get user input
            message = input()

            # Send the message to the server
            client_socket.send(message.encode())

        except:
            # If there is an error, break the loop and close the connection
            break

# Start two threads for receiving and sending messages
receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
send_thread = threading.Thread(target=send)

receive_thread.start()
send_thread.start()
```

**serverCon.py**

```
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 8080

# Create a socket object
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to a specific host and port
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))

# Listen for incoming connections
server_socket.listen()

print(f"Server is listening on {HOST}:{PORT}")

# List to store connected clients
clients = []

def handle_client(client_socket):
    """Thread to handle each client connection"""
    while True:
        try:
            # Receive data from the client
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)

            if not data:
                # If no data is received, break the loop and close the connection
                break

            # Send the received data to the other connected client
            for client in clients:
                if client != client_socket:
                    client.send(data)

        except:
            # If there is an error, break the loop and close the connection
            break

    # Remove the client from the list of connected clients
    clients.remove(client_socket)
    client_socket.close()

def start_server():
    """Function to start the server"""
    while True:
        # Accept incoming connections
        client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()

        # Add the client to the list of connected clients
        clients.append(client_socket)

        print(f"New client connected: {address}")

        # Start a new thread to handle the client connection
        client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket,))
        client_thread.start()

# Start the server
start_server()
```

What I want is to have the webcam feed running non-stop on one client that is also running the algorithm on that feed and then each time an event occurs which creates a message, that message is sent to the other client.

I can't understand what the problem is and have very little experience in server-client programming. I know some of the code is unnecessary, will clean it up when it starts working.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into why what you did doesn't work you can try and use something like [imagezmq](https://github.com/jeffbass/imagezmq).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34548018)

Comment: The answer I gave is a suggestion to use a well established library instead of writing hacky code.
Essentially the first code example in that github repo will give him exactly what he needs.